# Vertx timer change delay

Tags: timer, delay, vert.x

Need helps with timer:)
I need to create a repated timer in vertx, with a delay that changes.

The parameter delay value - is saved in my DB.
let's say we start with 10 seconds.

when I run the handler every 10 seconds I am checking my DataBase.

If the value - delay changes, I want to update the delay timer

Do you know how can I write a timer with changing delay?

****public void initTimer()** {**

```
    long delayFromDB = getDelayFromDB(); 
    setPeriodicTimer(delayFromDB);
```

**}**

**public long setPeriodicTimer(long delayFromDB) {**

```
long timerID = vertx.setPeriodic(delayFromDB, new Handler<Long>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(Long timerID) {
    long currDelayFromDB = getDelayFromDB(); 
    doSomeOperation();
    newDelayFromDB = getDelayFromDB(); 

    if(currDelayFromDB != newDelayFromDB ) {
      restartTimerWithNewDelay(newDelayFromDB , timerID);
    }
  }
});
return timerID;
```

}

**public void restartRefreshTimerWithNewTtl(long newDelayFromDB , Long timerID) {**

```
  //cancel last timer: timerID and  restart timer with the new delay    
  vertx.cancelTimer(timerID);
  setPeriodicTimer(newDelayFromDB );
```

}

**And is it ok to cancel timer and create another one right after, from the handle of the timer that will be canceled now. like here ?** (in this function restartRefreshTimerWithNewTtl)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works. Another approach would be to not use `setPeriodic` but just a regular timer and re-start a timer every time. So instead of :

```java
if(currDelayFromDB != newDelayFromDB ) {
      restartTimerWithNewDelay(newDelayFromDB , timerID);
}
```

You would do something like:

```java
vertx.setTimer(newDelayFromDB , task);
```

Comment: Thank you:) I forget to add that the delay don't change often, so it can be  less efficient to create every time again with setTimer?

Comment: And do you know to answer it ok to cancel timer and create another one right after, from the handle of the canceled function?

Comment: Yes, you can cancel a timer (next call), within a timer handler. This works because all runs on the same eventloop (thread).